# Select duplicate rows with a distinct column

Tags: sql, duplicates, unique

I need help writing a query that will return rows that contain duplicate values (AccountID) but only where the row contains a unique or distinct column value (AgentID), eg:

The Agent table:

```
AgentID - AccountID
2         ABCD
1         AI00
3         ABCD
4         BI00
5         ABCD
5         ABCD
```

Result:

```
Account   Count(*)
ABCD      2
```

(The last two rows are ignored because the AgentID is not unique).

Thank-you.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Why you want last 2 rows to be ignored? 
you should ignore the last row only leaving the second last row. Otherwise you'll loose data for the id 5.
Yet do you still want to ignore last two rows?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this query:

```
SELECT AgentID, AccountID
FROM dbo.Agents a
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Agents a2
    WHERE a.AccountID = a2.AccountID
    AND   a.AgentID <> a2.AgentID
)
GROUP BY AgentID, AccountID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68a89/3/0)</kbd>

It returns all rows which contain duplicate `AccountID` but where the combination of `AgentID` and `AccountID` is unique. In your sample it is:

```
AgentID      AccountID
2            ABCD
3            ABCD
```

So it omits the last two rows even if it has the same duplicate `AccountID` because they have the same `AgentID`.

Comment: Thank-you, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I think of this as two aggregations.  The first is at the `AgentId`/`AccountId` level to get the unique pairs.  The second is at the `AccountId` level to get the number for a given account:

```
select AccountId, count(*)
from (select AgentId, AccountId
      from agents
      group by AgentId, AccountId
      having count(*) = 1
     ) aa
group by AccountId
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank-you. How would I join the result set of this query to a second table (agents detail)  that has a key column of AgentId in order to view the other columns in the second table?

Comment: @Sanxion . . . You should ask a different question.  That seems materially different from this question.